# Getting All of Facebook Friends in Cordova Phonegap Application

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get facebook friends through Facebook Graph API on my Ionic Application. The plugin https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin was used.
When I use friend api, it only returns 12 friends. But in truth, there are more than 3000 friends. How can I get all friends?
Here is the code.

```
    function getFBFriends(eCallbackFunc)
    {
        facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me/friends?fields=uid', [],
            function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
                eCallbackFunc(response, null);
            },
            function(response)
            {
                eCallbackFunc(response, 'error');
            }
        );
    }
```

And the JSON response data is following as below:
[image]

How can I get all Facebook friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get friends who authorized your App too (with the `user_friends` permission). 12 friends authorized your App.

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's supposed to work with facebookConnectPlugin.api but they are facing some stability issues. You can follow up here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/468

Anyway, I downloaded the version from the dev branch and it works as expected.